# Debouncing in react using settimeout and setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, settimeout, debouncing

Is this acceptable code? I have tested it and it works, but I don't know if it is good practice. I am basically calling data every time someone types something into the input. But that is too many API calls. So I did what is called 'debouncing' so the API call is made when they stopped typing.

I guess the easier way is to have a button so they make one call when they press it. But I am trying the input `onchange` method.

```
class Weather extends React.Component{
state={
    data:[],
    target:'',
    timer:null
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({timer:null})
}
handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({
        target: e.target.value
    })
    clearTimeout(this.state.timer);
    this.setState({timer:setTimeout(()=>{
        this.fetch_geocodes()
    },2000)})
}
```

Comment: You need to clear a timeout on unmount. There's no need to set a state on mount.

Comment: There is also no need to store the timer in state. Use an instance variable in the case of class-based components, or use a React ref to hold its value. I recommend the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid reason to use class component then there is nothing wrong with using debouncing in class components. If I was writing that class, i would make these improvements:

- use a constructor to initiate class properties, because it is a better practice.
- Initiate your timer outside the state, no need to pollute the state with timer.
- No need to call componentDidMount() function in your code.

With the above changes the new class would look like this :

```
class Weather extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data:[],
      target:'',
    };

    this.timer = null;
 }

  handleChange=(e)=>{
    this.setState({target: e.target.value})
    clearTimeout(this.timer); //if handlechange is called within 2 seconds again then clear timeout and the previous call to fetch_geocodes in wait will not execute
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.fetch_geocodes, 2000) // call fetch_geocodes after 2 seconds of wait
   }
}
```

If you don't have a valid reason to use a class component then use functional component, and consider looking at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ixb9090/debouncing-in-react-forms-enhance-performance-by-reducing-the-uneccessary-function-calls-in-your-603c05d9c75a) to implement debouncing in functional components